# Can scanning for viruses on one Os find viruses on another (with a dual-boot)?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, ubuntu-14.04

I dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows Xp. I have both Avast and Malwarebytes installed through Xp, and I was wondering if the occasional boot up and scan from Xp would also protect Ubuntu.
Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu itself is not susceptible to Windows malware, though it's not bulletproof. There are Linux AV's, such as ClamAV, which are designed to remove Windows malware (e.g. from a Linux mail server); I'm not sure if it has much added value for Linux security. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clam_AntiVirus and http://www.clamav.net/index.html for more information on ClamAV, and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus for Ubuntu's comments.

The most important thing, for Linux, is to keep software updated, which Ubuntu does automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

As DrMoishe Pippik says, using Linux to scan your windows drives can be a good idea.

There are other specialized "distributions" that run antivirus software, like a live iso/disk. There used to be several, but I'm not too sure how many there are now... These ones look like they're still going, some are just applications for linux, some their own "live iso":

- [F-PROT Antivirus for Linux Workstations - for home use](http://www.f-prot.com/download/home_user/download_fplinux.html)
- [Panda Antivirus Linux 7.01.00-1](http://panda-antivirus.en.malavida.com/linux/)
- [Avira Rescue System - Avira Rescue CD](https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system)
- [Kasperski](http://support.kaspersky.com/linux_file80#downloads) (trial version only, or paid?)